# Constructing a several wav files from one source wav

Tags: python, audio, scipy

I have one source wav. file where i have recorded 5 tones separated by silence.
I have to make 5 different wav. files containing only this tones (without any silence)
I am using scipy.
I was trying to do sth similar as in this post: [constructing a wav file and writing it to disk using scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444965/constructing-a-wav-file-and-writing-it-to-disk-using-scipy)
but it does not work for me.
Can you please advise me how to do it ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform **silence detection** to identify the tones starts and ends. You can use a measurement of magnitude, such as the [root mean square](https://duckduckgo.com/Root_mean_square).

[Here's how to do a RMS using `scipy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433184/1595865)

Depending on your noise levels, this may be hard to do programmatically. You may want to consider simply using a audio editor, such as [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)